# Sequence of continuous functions that convergent to the indicator function pointwisely.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, pointwise-convergence, rectangles

Let $L=[a_1, b_1]\times \cdots \times [a_n,b_n]$ be a closed rectangle in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Prove that there exists a sequence of continuous functions $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ s.t. each $f_n$ is defined on $\mathbb{R^n}$  and pointwisely convergents to the indicator function $\chi_L$.

I thought $f_n=\chi_{[a_1-\frac{1}{n}, b_1+\frac{1}{n}]\times \cdots \times [a_n-\frac{1}{n},b_n+\frac{1}{n}]}$ seems to work but this is not continuous.

I have no idea how I should determine $f_n$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to approximate $\chi_{[a,b]}$ using piecewise linear functions which restrict to $\chi_{[a - 1/n, b + 1/n]}$ and then multiply to generalize to higher dimensions using the fact that projection onto coordinates is continuous.

Comment: Hint: definte $K_n = \{ x \mid d(x,L) \leqslant \frac{1}{n}\}$ and $F_n = \{ x \mid d(x,L) \geqslant \frac{2}{n}\}$ and look at $f_n(x) = \frac{d(x,F_n)}{d(x,F_n) + d(x,K_n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can convolve the indicator function with the $n$-dimensional heat kernel

$$\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\int_L \mathrm{e}^{-\dfrac{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2}{4t}}  \mathrm{d}y $$

Taking $t=1/n$ in the above given an appropriate sequence $f_n$.